# How can I restart Unity if it hangs

Tags: unity, freeze, restart

On my Ubuntu 15.10 PC, Unity sometimes hangs. It happens quite seldom, but I have no idea what to do when it does. Additional info:
1) The mouse pointer is moving as if everything is OK, but clicks do not affect the UI.
2) The terminal session won't open with Ctrl-Alt-F1.

**UPD 1.** Just found out that the keyboard is not active at all when Unity freezes (all indicators are disabled).

**UPD 2.** That's a desktop computer. Tell me if you need other specifications.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CTRL+ALT+X on at least xfce to force close a program. If that doesn't work, try adding a shortcut to xkill in your shortcuts menu. If the keyboard just completely doesn't work, you might have to restart the computer.

What are you using to run unity? There may be a problem with that because I've never had my keyboard break through the playonlinux script.

Comment: Sorry for not replying before, Azdrif. CTRL+ALT+X doesn't work even when system is working normally. I can be mistaken about the keyboard. Also, could you possibly tell more about adding a shortcut to xkill? Of course, restarting the computer with the power button does work, but I hope there's a better solution (like task manager on Windows). Unity launches as it normally does on Ubuntu.